# Using Asterisk to Click2Dial Via Command Line

Tags: command-line, asterisk, sip

I'd like to make an in house click2dial application the problem is I'm not sure how to get Asterisk via the command line to dial myself and then dial an extension like google voice does now or how grand central did.

I know about the Dial() command in Asterisk and the T option for transfer. Anyone have any insight on this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have something like this in your `extensions.conf`:

```
[outbound]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@provider,,T)
```

Then have a look at the originate CLI command:

```
*CLI> help originate
```

And then you can do something like:

```
$ asterisk -rx "originate SIP/1000 extension 4105556666@outbound"
```

Where `SIP/1000` is the local user and `4105556666` is the number you want that SIP phone connected with.